# Nginx rewrite variables a little off / confusing

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, nginx

Weird issue with my Nginx conf file. I have it rewriting certain paths via @rewrite, and everything else (all errors) go to a controller PHP script. Mainly to handle a non-existent "/index.php" redirecting properly. Request vars are also passed. However, the first variable is always "q" in the example below.

From my conf file:

```
error_page 403 404 500 502 503 504 = /error.html;

location = /error.html {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /path/to/controller.php?q=$request_uri;
}

location / { 
    try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrites;
}


location @rewrites {
    rewrite ^/example1/([A-Za-z0-9/.-]+)/       /path/script1.php?var=$1 last;
    rewrite ^/example2/([A-Za-z0-9/.-]+)/       /path/script2.php?var=$1 last;
    rewrite ^/example3/([A-Za-z0-9/.-]+)/       /path/script3.php?var=$1 last;
}
```

So when I have a url like //domain.com/?var1=1&var2=2 and check request variables in PHP I get back:

q = /?var1=1

var2 = 2

I can see how this happens due to the rewrite, but trying various other examples, removing the variable and permutations of this method have not be helpful. My question is, is there a way to retain this setup, using rewrites for certain paths, errors for everything else, and pass all requests variables at the same time (not just the vars after the first)?

**Edit: fixed the issue**

Rather than pointing the error pages to /error.html I just point it to the controller file and the problem seems to be resolved (passing all variables correctly).

```
error_page 403 404 500 502 503 504 = /path/to/controller.php?q=$request_uri;
```

no need for that "location = /error.html" snippet.

Comment: Is you problem that `q` contains `/?var1=1`, not `/?var1=1&var2=2`?

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying. The problem I have is that the first get variable is always gone. Not a game breaker, but not convenient either. E.g. If I passed one GET var, i would not be able to retrieve it. The second and so on vars pass just fine.

Comment: It's because you have weird rewrite in error.html block. What is it for?

Comment: So that errors get redirected to a PHP page. I could put 'try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrites;' in the error redirect, but that doesn't seem to forward any variables to @rewrites.

Comment: Mainly, I don't use an index.php page in the root directory, so I work around that by forwarding the error.

Comment: thanks for looking into this Alexey.